# Could a slow join on two tables be avoided by adding the desired columns from one to the other, or do I have bad relationships?

Tags: mysql

I have Table A

```
+-------------+---------+----------+
| id          | int     | NOT NULL |
| name        | varchar | NOT NULL |
| number      | varchar | NOT NULL |
| description | varchar | NOT NULL |
| type        | varchar | NOT NULL |
+-------------+---------+----------+
```

I then create table C

```
+--------+---------+----------+
| B_id   | int     | NOT NULL |
| number | varchar | NOT NULL |
| qty    | int     | NOT NULL |
+--------+---------+----------+
```

Our current query looks like the following:

```
SELECT C.*, A.* FROM C
JOIN A ON A.number = C.number
WHERE C.B_id = '<insert any number here>'
```

This join seems to be running a little slow even though we've created an INDEX on `A.number`. My question is, could we simply avoid the join by taking the desired columns we want from A and add them as columns in table C, or is this bad practice.

I ask this also because at my day job, in our schemas, we have several tables that reference the same column names from table to table. The are indexed, and from millions of rows of data pull seamlessly. Why can I not achieve this with such small tables? Am I setting up the relationships incorrectly?

Comment: How is table B relevant to this question?

Comment: I reference it in the query, so I didn't want it to be without context.

Comment: Where? You mean `B_id`? That could be anything.

Comment: fair enough I have removed it, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: and you also have an index on C.B_id?

Comment: must set the number column to varchar ? as usually,it should'n be slow although the rows count in millions.local query or remote query?

Comment: @anti-gravity - `number_col = 'number'` works fine (the inverse does not).

Comment: @MarkHill - anti-gravity may be complaining about `number | varchar`.  Please store numeric values in numeric datatypes.  (Or change your example to avoid distractions like this!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, violating normalization is sometimes necessary to resolve performance problems.

But you should try to avoid this, and only do it when absolutely necessary. Adding the redundant columns means you need to ensure that the columns in `C` are always in sync with `A`. You may be able to do this with triggers, but it adds complexity and performance impacts to all queries that update the tables.

This shouldn't normally be needed for individual columns that can be fetched using a simple join on indexed columns. It can be more useful for aggregated data, since queries that perform grouping and aggregation can be very expensive for large datasets. For instance, if you frequently need transaction totals by date, you could use the Event Scheduler to update a table with these totals every night. Past transactions are not usually changed, so you don't have to worry about this getting out of sync with the raw transactions table.

Answer (score 1):

Your particular query would benefit from this index:

```
C:  INDEX(B_id)
```

The query then would

1. find the *index* rows in C for the given `B_id`
2. reach over to C's data BTree to get `C.*`
3. use C.number to reach into A's `INDEX(number)`
4. reach over to A's data Btree to get `A.*`

If you don't need all of `*`, there may be further optimizations (by using a "covering" index).

Note:  The above assumes `ENGINE=InnoDB`.